# Regression result in keras using python

Tags: python, keras

This is a regression problem. Below is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score, KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Swapnil\Desktop\RP TD\first\Changes')

## Load the dataset
dataset1 = pd.read_csv("Main Lane Plaza 1.csv")
X_train = dataset1.iloc[:,0:11].values
Y_train = dataset1.iloc[:,11].values
dataset2 = pd.read_csv("Main Lane Plaza 1_070416010117.csv")
X_test = dataset2.iloc[:,0:11].values
Y_test = dataset2.iloc[:,11].values

##Define base model
def base_model():
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(11, input_dim=11, kernel_initializer='normal', 
activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(7, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'adam')
return model

seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)

clf = KerasRegressor(build_fn=base_model, nb_epoch=100, 
batch_size=5,verbose=0)

clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
res = clf.predict(X_train)

##Result
clf.score(X_test, Y_test)
```

Not sure if the score should be negative?? 
Kindly advise if i am doing something wrong.
Thanks in advance.

I am not able to figure it out can this be problem due to feature scaling as I did feature scaling using R and saved the csv files to use in python.

Comment: I tried editing but couldn't. Please format the code and give more information

Comment: @SagarBHathwar  could you pls check now if possible thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you get a negative score for regression problem, it usually means that your the model you choose can't fit your data well.

Answer (score 0):

You have layer 1 activation as sigmoid, layer 2 also as sigmoid and then final layer as 1 output.

change the activations to `relu`, as `sigmoid` would be squashing the values between 0 to 1. Making the numbers really small, causing the vanishing gradient problem over the 2 hidden layer.

```
def base_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(11, input_dim=11, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(7, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model
```